# Django model order_by based on another model queryset length

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have 2 models:

`models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    content = models.TextField()
    uploadedBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
LIKE_CATEGORIES = (
    ("LIKE", "LIKE"),
    ("DISLIKE", "DISLIKE")
)

class PostLike(models.Model):
    _type = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=LIKE_CATEGORIES, blank=True, null=True)
    
    content = models.ForeignKey(
        Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to order `Post` based on number of likes a post has. Number of likes a post has is the count of `PostLike` objects having `_type="LIKE",content=post_object`.

How can I order `Post` specifically based on number of likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can annotate each Post with a [Count](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#id8) of related PostLike objects, this can have a filter to only count the related objects that satisfy a condition. Then order by the annotation

```
from django.db.models import Count, Q
Post.objects.annotate(
    likes=Count('postlike', filter=Q(postlike___type="LIKE"))
).order_by('-likes')
```

I'm not sure having a field with an underscore prefix is the best idea, it may mess up the ORM and other parts of the Django internals

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer!!!! BTW, should I rename `_type` to `type`, Cuz `type` is a python keyword. Can I? Or will it cause some other issues?

Comment: @PranavaMohan `type` should be fine, or you could use `category` if you want to avoid the built-in since you are already using that word in the choices?

Answer (score 1):

This will restrict your filter to Post with LIKE and also rank it

```py
from django.db.models import Count
Post.objects.filter(postlike___type='LIKE').annotate(likes=Count('postlike')).order_by('-likes')

Or

from django.db.models import Count
Post.objects.filter(postlike___type='LIKE').annotate(Count('postlike'))[::-1]
```